# using function to search for two text values in a kml file not just one Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

Ok I have this:

```
filterMarkersstyle: function (text) {
    if (text === undefined || text === null) {
        text = '';
    }
    var t = text.toLowerCase().trim(),
        isVisible,
        ms = this.mapshapes,
        mss, shapeId, it;
    for (shapeId in ms) {
        if (ms.hasOwnProperty(shapeId)) {
            mss = ms[shapeId];
            if (t === undefined && t === '') {
                this.setMapObjectVisibility(mss, true);
            } else {
                descrip = mss.description;
                if (descrip !== undefined) {
                    it = descrip.toLowerCase();
                    isVisible = (it.search(t) !== -1) ? true : false;
                    this.setMapObjectVisibility(mss, isVisible);
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Which currently search for map markers on a kml file and set the display to visible if the text passed to the function exists.
I need to expand it to deal with various marker types not just one.
How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok to fill in some details I eneded up sending a regex to the kmlmapparser:

like so:

```
var arr = ['place1', 'place2'];
var joined = arr.map(function (val) {
    return val + ' all ' + name;
}).join('|');
var kmlmatcher = '(' + joined + ')';
var regnew = new RegExp(kmlmatcher, "i");
kmlLayer.filterMarkersstyle(regnew);
```